# Проверка типа файла Java

Tags: java, файлы, fileupload

Подскажите как проверить тип или расширение файла? Я проверяю файл на расширение, в конце имени. Но я знаю что можно его изменить и, допустим, файл это картинка а мы изменили расширение на `txt`.

Спасибо.

Comment: то есть программа должна понимать что за тип файла, если даже мы поменяли расширение? то есть взяли png  и изменили на txt. а программа тебе говорит, что читает txt, но на самом деле это png?

Comment: @SeniorPomidor нет. программа будет говорить что то `png`. Как-то слышал такое. К примеру если открыть картинку при помощи `Notepad++` то в начале будет формат или расширение, и даже если изменить расширение у файла всё равно останется то.

Comment: Посмотрите тут: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51438/getting-a-files-mime-type-in-java

Comment: Содержимое файла - это набор байт. Как их интерпретировать решать вам. Расширение - это часть имени файла. Определить формат файла по содержимому можно, если оно соответствует спецификации формата, т.е. записано по правилам, по которым можно определить формат. В общем случае это не решаемо.